# Executing a "long-length" Oracle command in C++

Tags: c++, oracle, mfc

**Problem:** I have a C++ application that executes different Oracle commands. My application can execute this SQL statement the following way (I have ommited error checking and a few earlier steps):

```
strcpy(szProcName,"select grantee, granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS;");
rc=SQLPrepare(sqlc.g_hstmt,(SQLCHAR*)szProcName,(SQLINTEGER)strlen(szProcName));
rc = SQLExecute(sqlc.g_hstmt);
```

The select statement's data is placed/binded into an MFC List Control.  This works without problem...

*The issue comes when I try to execute long-length select statements.*
I now wish to use the same method, but to run this *long* SQL statement:

```
SELECT  a.GRANTEE, a.granted_role as "Connect", b.granted_role as "APPUSER" FROM
(SELECT GRANTEE, granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTED_ROLE = 'CONNECT')  a
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT GRANTEE, granted_role from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where GRANTED_ROLE = 'APPUSER') b
ON a.GRANTEE=b.GRANTEE;
```

Setting that entire statement into `szProcName` seems like the wrong way to go about things.

**What I have tried:**  I tried to add all the SQL text into `szProcName`, but it does not fit and makes the code terribly messy.  I also thought to create a Stored Procedure to call in C++.  The Stored Procedure requires that I use an `INTO` clause and does not produce a table that I can use in C++.  Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** I have found one working way. By increasing `szProcName`'s size and using`strcat()`, I can add each line and then execute.  I still wonder if there is a more appropriate way, especially if my statements become any larger (which they probably will).

Comment: I don't see any problem with that.  It is hardly "long"

Comment: Does it really work? There should be no semicolon at the end of SQL statement. What library are you using? It does not look like pure OCI. How you allocate szProcName and why to you use it?

Comment: It does really work.  I am using Oracle 3.8.  I allocated szProcName by creating it as `char szProcName[500];`.  It is used to hold the string of text that I execute as SQL code.  I am using libraries `<sql.h>` and `<sqlext.h>`

Comment: I think 3.8 is your Oracle Enterprise Linux version (OEL).  You are probably running oracle 11g or possibly 12c.

Comment: If it is MFC use CString. If you are more comfortable with STL use std::string. Then you will not have to worry about the buffer size

Comment: Thanks. @jimmcnamara I am running 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one working way. By increasing szProcName's size and using strcat(), I can add each line and then execute. I still wonder if there is a more appropriate way, especially if my statements become any larger (which they have).